# Jquery hover event issue on chrome

Tags: jquery

I have problem when I try to change the content of my element using jQuery. Everything work fine in Internet explorer but in Google Chrome the mouse over action works fine but on mouse out event nothing will change! Here is my code:

```js
$(".changedata").hover(function() {
  $(this).html('<span class="rate">8.9</span>');
}, function() {
  $(this).html('<i class="material-icons">star</i>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="changedata">
  <i class="material-icons">star</i>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using `.on('hover')`

Comment: I placed your code in an executable snippet. It appears to work fine in Chrome (and indeed all browsers). Please check your console for errors. If you still have issues I'd suggest you include a more complete example with more of your HTML and CSS included.

Answer (score 0):

somehow it worked by this changes:

```
$(".changedata").hover(
         function () {
            var value = $(this).attr('data-change');
            $(this).html(value);

        },
        function(){
             $(this).html('<i class="material-icons">star</i>');

        }
    );
```